# How do I make a CM view show one of two child views, all (including parent) bound to the same view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I use the **view model first** approach in a **Caliburn Micro** project.

I have a view, say, `EmployeeSearchView`, bound to `EmployeeSearchViewModel`.  It has a content area that should show *either* a grid or a list view of some result data.

I *could* expose a child view model, say, `EmployeeSearchResultsViewModel`, and use the `View.Context` attached property to choose between `EmployeeSearchResults.GridView` and `EmployeeSearchResults.ChildView`.  However, I **don't want that extra child view model**; the data I need to display is in a property of `EmployeeSearchViewModel`.

I would *like* to have my **child region** display a **different view bound to the same view model as its parent** view.  Can this be done?  I've tried this, inserted at the relevant point in `EmployeeSearchView`:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" cal:View.Context="{Binding Mode}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

I see an error in the Debug pane:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree. This could indicate a cycle in the tree.
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInTree(FrameworkElement feStart, FrameworkContentElement fceStart, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, InheritanceBehavior& inheritanceBehavior, Object& source)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, Boolean isImplicitStyleLookup, Object& source)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindImplicitStyleResource(FrameworkElement fe, Object resourceKey, Object& source)
```

The CM logging subsequently suggests that things have been wired up correctly, but the views do not display.

```
Info: Binding MyProject.Views.EmployeeSearchView and MyProject.ViewModels.EmployeeSearchViewModel.
Info: Attaching MyProject.Views.EmployeeSearchView to MyProject.ViewModels.EmployeeSearchViewModel.
Info: Binding MyProject.Views.EmployeeSearch.GridView and MyProject.ViewModels.EmployeeSearchViewModel.
Info: Setting DC of MyProject.Views.EmployeeSearch.GridView to MyProject.ViewModels.EmployeeSearchViewModel.
Info: Attaching message handler MyProject.ViewModels.EmployeeSearchViewModel to MyProject.Views.EmployeeSearch.GridView.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a neat idea, I hadn't considered composing a view like that before, and it certainly sounds possible. I just had a quick try using a test project, and I was able to get the behaviour you're after, essentially doing exactly what you're describing.

A quick look at the test classes/XAML I used:

`TestViewModel.cs`

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
    public string AnotherTestProperty { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        TestProperty = "A Testing String.";
        AnotherTestProperty = "Another Testing String";
        Mode = "Test"; // Hard Coded to my Test Context
    }
}
```

`TestView.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.TestView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="This is the main TestViewModel I can bind to properties out here:"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TestProperty" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="AnotherTestProperty" />
        <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" cal:View.Context="{Binding Mode}" Grid.Row="1" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`Test.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Test.Test"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="#FF2BFB16">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="This is another View, It's also attached to the Test ViewModel."/>
        <TextBlock Text="I can bind to the same properties in here:" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="TestProperty" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="AnotherTestProperty" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Which produces this (far from pretty) result:

[image]

I think you're on the right track, and I suspect the problem (based on the error message), is either to do with the `Mode`, or the design of your `View`. I get problems if I attempt to specify a `Mode` which doesn't exist, as a quick test try hard coding the name of your `Mode`.

It could be that one of your `Views` is attempting to compose the main EmployeeSearchView as a child, which will itself contain another `EmployeeSearchView` view, and so on (the View would never be able to resolve itself).